# Set grid cells that do not overlap with polygons to NA

Tags: r, extract, polygon, mask, r-raster

I want to extract those grid cells that are overlapped with the polygons. I used "crop" and "mask", but it not working properly and did not detect all the grid cells correctly.

```
#US shapefile
Us <- readOGR(dsn ="C:/shapefile",layer="boundaries") # read shapefile

#ozone ncdf file
data <- brick(path="C:/",pattern = "nc", varname = "o3")
data_us <- crop(data, Us)
data_us2 <- mask(data_us, Us)

#urban shapefile
urban <- readOGR("C:/shapefile_urban") # read shapefile
urban_T <- st_as_sf(spTransform(urban, CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
+ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"))) # Transform projection

#mask with urban
data_us3 <- crop(data_us2, urban_T)
data_us4 <- mask(data_us3, urban_T)

df_i <- as.data.frame(data_us4, xy = TRUE)
names(df_i) <- c("Longitude", "Latitude", "value")
df_i <- na.omit(df_i)

#Plot
ggplot(df_i, aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude, fill = value)) +
geom_tile() +
#add US map layer with state boundaries
geom_map(data = map_data("state"), map = map_data("state"),
     aes(long, lat, map_id = region), 
     color = "black", fill = NA,size = 0.5) +
expand_limits(x = map_data("state")$long, y = map_data("state")$lat)
```

Result:
[image]

But there are more grids that overlapped by polygons:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain the desired output using `mask` from the `terra` package, since this function has the `touches` argument (which is not available in the `raster` package `mask`). Since you did not add a minimal reproducible example, here is one.

## Example data

```
library(terra)
library(raster)
library(sf)

# Create example data
rast1 <- rast(matrix(rnorm(225,50,20), 15))

vect1 <- vect("POLYGON ((6.5 6.5, 6.2 7.8, 7.3 7.3, 7.5 6.2, 6.5 6.5))")

# Show example data
plot(rast1)
plot(vect1, add = T)
```

[image: example]

## Mask with terra package

```
# touches = T is the default, but adding it to make it explicit
plot(terra::mask(rast1, vect1, touches = T))
```

[image: maskw/terra]

## Mask with raster package

```
rast2 <- raster::raster(rast1)
# Convert vect1 to sf to use raster::mask
plot(raster::mask(rast2, st_as_sf(vect1)))
```

[image: maskw/raster]